# Check if a latitude and longitude is within a circle google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

**Below is the desired result, which I'm looking for**

[image]

**What I would like to know is:**

I have created the circle using center point lat lang and radius around it. Now I want to know, how to check (calculate) if a latitude and longitude is either inside or outside the area I would appreciate if you can give me code example in Javascript. I'm using Google Maps API V3.

**I found this function but not working as expected for me:**

```
function arePointsNear(checkPoint, centerPoint) {
    var sw = new google.maps.LatLng(centerPoint.lat() - 0.005, centerPoint.lng() - 0.005);
    var ne = new google.maps.LatLng(centerPoint.lat() + 0.005, centerPoint.lng() + 0.005);
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(sw, ne);
    if (bounds.contains (checkPoint)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Any help will be great.. thanks in advance!!

Comment: A circle has a constant radius. If your circle has a 10km radius, check whether the point is  within 10km to the circle center point. If it is, it means the point is within the circle.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

For such short distances, and when the accuracy doesn't have to be exact to the centimeter, you can treat the surface of the earth as flat. Calculate a conversion from degrees to kilometers at the latitude of the center point, then the [Pythagorean theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) can be used to get the distance:

```
function arePointsNear(checkPoint, centerPoint, km) {
  var ky = 40000 / 360;
  var kx = Math.cos(Math.PI * centerPoint.lat / 180.0) * ky;
  var dx = Math.abs(centerPoint.lng - checkPoint.lng) * kx;
  var dy = Math.abs(centerPoint.lat - checkPoint.lat) * ky;
  return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) <= km;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/57gQa/

Note: The code doesn't take into consideration if you are passing the 0/360 longitude. If that is the case, you would have to normalize the longitudes first.

Comment: Really appreciated mate. It is working and showing results which I was looking for. You have saved my life!! To be honest I'm not good in maths, so I am looking for another favour i.e. if you can help me understand the values like what is in **var ky, kx** or would be great if you can **comment the code**. In JSfiddle example you took 10 as km but is it really acting as **km** or **meters**?

Comment: @colourtheweb: The `ky` and `kx` values are km per degree for the latitude and longitude, respectively. The `kx` value gets smaller when you get closer to the poles, as the degree lines are closer together. The distance between the cities in the fiddle is almost 91 km, and the 10 used as threshold is really km, not meters. You can see the distance and use of thresholds 90 and 91 km: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/57gQa/1/

Comment: asking this question very late as it's been 3 years. I was explaining it to someone and wanted to clear my doubts. Can you tell me what exactly are we calulating in **kx**, **dx** and **dy**. Also did you named the variables kx, ky and dx, dy for X-axis and Y-axis ? Thanks in advance, I look forward to your answer.

Comment: wow, you are just epic. humanity smiles upon the shine you provide.

Comment: The Maps API has geometry functions to calculate distances. You really don't need that.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a little [spherical trig](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_trigonometry)

First you need the central angle theta of the [arc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_%28geometry%29) subtended by your distance (L = 10 km).

```
L = theta*r
```

where r is the radius of the earth (6378.135 km)

Now, if the central angle between the point of interest and your center point is < theta, it is inside your circle.  Call this angle theta_p.

Here's a diagram illustrating a spherical triangle:
[spherical triangle image http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Spherical_trigonometry_basic_triangle.svg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Spherical_trigonometry_basic_triangle.svg)

edit - sorry, apparently I don't know how to link to an image??  Here's the URL:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Spherical_trigonometry_basic_triangle.svg

In this case, two of the sides of the spherical triangle (call them *a, b*) are the difference in longitude and difference in latitude of the points respectively.  The included angle *C* is 90 degrees (angle between lines of longitude and lines of latitude.

The spherical trig law of cosines is:

```
cos(c) = cos(a)*cos(b) + sin(a)*sin(b)*cos(C)
```

*c* is the central angle between your points, which we earlier called theta_p

edit - this solution isn't limited to small distance WRT the radius of the earth, as the other suggestions are.