# check if a coordinate is contained within a circle in google maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to make an application that tells me if a coordinate is contained in a `circle`.

for that every time I click on a point on the map a I get the coordinate.I would like to know if that new coordinate is contained within the circle or not

I would also like to know how I can make a circle occupy 5 meters around from a coordinate. in my example the radius is: `50000` but I do not know how to perform the conversion to set the value in meters.

this is my code:

http://plnkr.co/edit/OI4sjcuS526rFYxPnvDv?p=preview

```
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat:4.624335 , lng: -74.063644 },
        zoom: 5,
    });

    //circle coordinates
    var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        map: map,
        radius: 50000,    
        fillColor: '#FFFFFF',
        opacity:0,
        center:{lat:4.624335 , lng: -74.063644 }
    });   

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
        //I get new coordinates ( e.latLng)
    });
}
```

thanks!

**Updated**

They have marked this question as a duplicate, with this solution
(http://jsfiddle.net/kaiser/wzcst/embedded/result/)

but it does not really satisfy my problem, because as you can see in the image, the solution fails.

[image]

Comment: @geocodezip my question is not duplicated, That answer does not solve my problem. I need to know if a coordinate is contained within a circle and in the example that you gave me you can clearly see how the coordinate is outside the circle and it is marked that it is contained.

Comment: Please use the fiddle in the answer, not the question before you say it doesn't work.

Comment: I can see the same happening. Looks like distance calculation (`computeDistanceBetween`) and the actual circle radius differ by a few meters. Did you try with a smaller circle? I wonder if this could be due to earth curvature (?). Is a circle geodesic at all times? And what about the method to compute the distance? That said, your question is still a duplicate, as marked.

Comment: @MrUpsidown what happens is that for some reason the circle seems to be enclosed in a rectangle. and that's why at that point, the marker seems to be inside that rectangle. Maybe the question can be duplicated, but the answer does not satisfy my need. can you help me please?

Comment: @geocodezip This "solution" is not exact. You can clearly see in my image that the marker is not included in the circle and it says that it is contained. This is because a kind of rectangle is created inside the circle, therefore it is not inside the circle. If you could help me with this, I would be very pleased.

Comment: Looks to me (from the update to your question) like you used the fiddle in the question, not the one in the answer.  Can't tell that from the picture.

Comment: Excuse me, my native language is Spanish, I'm not sure what you're saying. this is the jsdfiddle of the supposed "solution" http://jsfiddle.net/kaiser/wzcst/  where it is shown that the marker is outside the circle and says that it is contained within the circle. and this is my code: http://plnkr.co/edit/OI4sjcuS526rFYxPnvDv?p=preview  where I am ready to receive a new coordinate and do something to calculate if said coordinate is inside the circle

Comment: What you are describing is from the fiddle from the duplicate **question** and not from the **answer** posted there. Because the person who asked the question was using a `LatLngBounds` object (which is always a rectangle or square). The solution is to calculate the distance from the center of the circle. Still, I notice that it doesn't seem very accurate. Trying to find out why...

Comment: And for your question *"how to perform the conversion to set the value in meters"*: There is no conversion to do, the value **is** in meters! Just [read the docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/polygon#CircleOptions).

Comment: @MrUpsidown thanks.. I had tried this for my case: `var coordinates = e.latLng;
          var circleArea = circle.getBounds();
        var isContained = circleArea.contains(coordinates);` what do you think?

Comment: @geocodezip I am voting to reopen this question as the solution provided in the duplicate question seems buggy. I opened [an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79732400). Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/n88rdrvk/).

Comment: @yavg Nope. That won't work. The solution, once again, is to calculate the distance from the marker to the circle center but it seems buggy. See my above comment.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As from what I have understood in your question, what your'e trying to do is

1. display the map
2. create a circle in map
3. upon clicking in the map,
   determine if the point is outside or inside the circle

There is a post about this here in SO: [Check if a latitude and longitude is within a circle google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24680247/check-if-a-latitude-and-longitude-is-within-a-circle-google-maps). If you check on the accepted answer (credits to [Guffa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/69083/guffa) for the genius algorithm), he used this function to check if the point is within the radius:

```
// credits to user:69083 for this specific function
function arePointsNear(checkPoint, centerPoint, km) { 
   var ky = 40000 / 360;
   var kx = Math.cos(Math.PI * centerPoint.lat / 180.0) * ky;
   var dx = Math.abs(centerPoint.lng - checkPoint.lng) * kx;
   var dy = Math.abs(centerPoint.lat - checkPoint.lat) * ky;
   return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) <= km;
}
```

Now as for what you are trying to achieve, you could just simply add this inside your click event. Here's what I did:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
  var click = event.latLng;
  var locs = {lat: event.latLng.lat(), lng: event.latLng.lng()};
  var n = arePointsNear(user, locs, diameter);
```

Then I added the condition that if the function returns true, the marker will have a label "**I**" (short for inside).

```
  if(n){
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: locs,
      label: {
        text:"I", //marking all jobs inside radius with I
        color:"white"
      }
    });
```

Then if it didn't, the marker will then be marked "**O**" (short for outside)...

```
  }else{
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: locs,
      label: {
        text:"O", //marking all jobs outside radius with O
        color:"white"
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Here's the sample application that I have created, just in case you want to see it in action:
http://jsbin.com/hujusod/edit?js,output

> This is a possible duplicate of [Check if a latitude and longitude is within a circle google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24680247/check-if-a-latitude-and-longitude-is-within-a-circle-google-maps)
>   . Or [How To Display Content Based on Closest Lat/Long to Entered Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49617713/how-to-display-content-based-on-closest-lat-long-to-entered-address).
>
> But since function is used in a different way, I posted my answer to help you do what you originally intended to. Feel free to upvote the answer from where the `arePointsNear` function came from if that's what you only need.

I hope this helped!

Comment: The [Geometry Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry) has functions to calculate distance (`computeDistanceBetween`). If you know the circle radius and center point, then it's easy to compute the distance and compare it with the radius.