# How to check if a point is near to any other point in an array Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I found an answer here that determines if two points are near each other based on a certain radius:

[Check if a latitude and longitude is within a circle google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24680247/check-if-a-latitude-and-longitude-is-within-a-circle-google-maps)

This is not the exact answer I am looking for however as I want to rewrite this function:

```
function arePointsNear(checkPoint, centerPoint, km) {
  var ky = 40000 / 360;
  var kx = Math.cos(Math.PI * centerPoint.lat / 180.0) * ky;
  var dx = Math.abs(centerPoint.lng - checkPoint.lng) * kx;
  var dy = Math.abs(centerPoint.lat - checkPoint.lat) * ky;
  return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) <= km;
}
```

To be able to check if the point of interest is within a certain distance of any other point in the array. Here is my attempt so far but does not work as expected:

```
function arePointsNear(checkPoint, centerPointArray, km) {
    var ky = 40000 / 360;
    for (var i = 0; i < centerPointArray.length; i++) {
        var kx = Math.cos(Math.PI * centerPointArray[i].lat / 180.0) * ky;
        var dx = Math.abs(centerPointArray[i].lng - checkPoint.lng) * kx;
        var dy = Math.abs(centerPointArray[i].lat - checkPoint.lat) * ky;
        if (Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) <= km) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

var centerPointArray = [
 { lat: -42.734358, lng: 147.439506, info: "T" },
 { lat: -42.735258, lng: 147.438000, info: "V" },
 { lat: -43.999792, lng: 170.463352, info: "W" }
]
```

Here is a link to the JS Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/ohb4puj2/3/

Upon opening up the debugger it does not return the desired result when the markers are moved to within a 10KM radius of each other

Comment: What i would recommend, is to just use googles spherical distance api and not roll your own distance. I was playing around on your fiddle, and the distance function you have implemented is wrong. Markers were saying they were 2000km away when they were sitting ontop of each other.

Comment: What is the "desired result?  Why do you expect that result?

Comment: If I replace your function with `computeDistanceBetween` from the geometry library, it works as I expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using filter() you can reduce the array down to the places that are within range.

```js
function arePointsNear(checkPoint, centerPoint, km) {
  var ky = 40000 / 360;
  var kx = Math.cos(Math.PI * centerPoint.lat / 180.0) * ky;
  var dx = Math.abs(centerPoint.lng - checkPoint.lng) * kx;
  var dy = Math.abs(centerPoint.lat - checkPoint.lat) * ky;
  return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) <= km;
}

var centerPointArray = [
 { lat: -42.734358, lng: 147.439506, info: "T" },
 { lat: -42.735258, lng: 147.438000, info: "V" },
 { lat: -43.999792, lng: 170.463352, info: "W" }
]


const checkPoint = { lat: -42.5, lng: 147.4 };
const distance = 50;
const withInRange = centerPointArray.filter( function (centerPoint) {
  return arePointsNear(checkPoint, centerPoint, distance);
});

console.log(withInRange);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is simple: just take the `return false` statement out of the for loop. This way, you will return `false` only if no point in the array was close enough. (right now, you return false if the first point is not close enough)

```
function arePointsNear(checkPoint, centerPointArray, km) {
    var ky = 40000 / 360;
    for (var i = 0; i < centerPointArray.length; i++) {
        var kx = Math.cos(Math.PI * centerPointArray[i].lat / 180.0) * ky;
        var dx = Math.abs(centerPointArray[i].lng - checkPoint.lng) * kx;
        var dy = Math.abs(centerPointArray[i].lat - checkPoint.lat) * ky;
        if (Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) <= km)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not. I added a link to a JS Fiddle to help explain what is going on here.